# Link pulse when autonegotiation is off on FE, GE Ethernet

Tags: ethernet

According to [Wikipedia about link pulse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation#Electrical_signals), link pulse is used to detect link failure/L1 status. Autonegotiation on FE and GE use link pulse mechanism.

When speed and duplex are forced and autonegotiation is turned off, is the interface still generate link pulse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is **no**.

Unfortunately, because of the history of Ethernet, you often see statements about it that are only true for 10Mb/s operation, or only for half-duplex operation and so forth.

802.3 clause 28.1.4.1 says:

> Auto-Negotiation does not support the transmission of the NLP sequence. The 10BASE-T PMA provides this function if it is connected to the MDI.

In other words, you don't get link test pulses sent if you force the speed to 100Mb/s or 1000Mb/s. They are unnecessary, because idle symbols are continuously transmitted in these modes.

Comment: Then how link status is determined up or down when speed and duplex are forced?

Comment: 100BASE-TX and above use a more sophisticated encoding than 10BASE-T which include 'special' symbols. Between frames, the transmitter is continually sending idle symbols. When the receiver has started to the decode these, it'll bring the link up.